# PHP PDO Query Not Working With Vars?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a little confused here. I've got the following code:

```
class Users {
    function count_matched_rows($needle, $haystack){
        global $userdb;

        $query = $userdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE ? = ?");
        $query->execute(array($haystack, $needle));

        return $query->fetchColumn();
    }
}

$users = new Users();
print_r($users->count_matched_rows("jeremyfifty9", "username"));
```

Which prints 0 with an expected value of 1. So I changed it to this:

```
class Users {
    function count_matched_rows($needle, $haystack){
        global $userdb;

        $query = $userdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'jeremyfifty9'");
        $query->execute(array($haystack, $needle));

        return $query->fetchColumn();
    }
}

$users = new Users();
print_r($users->count_matched_rows("jeremyfifty9", "username"));
```

Which prints 1 as expected. Does anybody know why the first code prints 0 but the second prints 1?

(BTW - I'm trying to get this to simulate `mysql_num_rows`)

Comment: You cannot use a placeholder / variable for the variable name, only for the value.

Comment: Obligatory "don't use `global` (especially in a class, but, really, never use it anywhere) comment.  Make $userdb a private member and pass it in via constructor.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Fixing that now (in my code). @jeroen, is it possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: I want to be able to use this function for any row though. With your alternative, do you mean having a switch statement and saying if $haystack = "username" then hardcode in the username?

Comment: I put it in an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a placeholder / variable for the variable name, only for the value.

You could just send the variable name and hard-code username in the query.

An alternative would be to check the variable name against a whitelist and use a valid name as a variable directly in the query:

```
$whitelist = array('username', ....);    // add all valid column names

// check for variable in whitelist
if (in_array($haystack, $whitelist))
{
  $query = $userdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `$haystack` = ?");
  $query->execute(array($needle));
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: @Nile You need to make sure your query is safe from sql injection.

Comment: Ah - that's right. I forgot that it wont sanitize it if I follow this method.

Comment: keep in mind that using PDO with placeholders doesn't sanitize the input per se; rather, it avoids the need for sanitization completely by sending the query to MySQL separately from sending the $needle. This paradigm also helps to see why the answer to this question is what it is;  using a "?" is a construct recognized by MySQL -- it is not a construct that makes PHP sanitize and concatenate into the query.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a variable for the column name. You can only use it for the column value.

The way you've done it, you're selecting all records where the string value of `$haystack` equals the string value of `$needle`. This will almost never be true. In the event that it is true, you it will just return all the rows in the table. Regardless, it is certainly not what you intended, and hopefully explains why it returns 0 results.

Comment: Does that mean it's impossible to do what I'm trying to do?